# how to remove mongodb collection if mongod doesn't start cause of broken collection?

Tags: mongodb, collections, wiredtiger

I can't start mongod cause of broken collection, mongod.log says:

```
2018-01-06T09:32:19.089+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] found 2 
index(es) that wasn't finished before shutdown
2018-01-06T09:32:19.089+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal assertion 
28579 UnsupportedFormat: Unable to find metadata for table:index-5155-
3080678491732636775 Index: {name: _id_, ns: gozazu.phones_10759} - 
version too new for this mongod. See 
http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.4-index-downgrade for detailed 
instructions on how to handle this error. at 
src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_index.cpp 241
2018-01-06T09:32:19.089+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Command mongod --repair doesn't help. How can i remove or fix this collection if mongo shell can't connect to mongod?

Comment: It seems that you have run newer version of mongod on your data. It created some metadata which the mongod that doesn't start can not understand _version too new for this mongod. See 
http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.4-index-downgrade_. I would start the newer mongod and fix problems as the mentioned link suggests.

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to update and skipped a release?